# Linker error after successful compilation

Tags: c, linker-errors

I have the following (pseudo) code:

`file.h`

```
extern int a;
extern int b;
extern int *c;
// function declarations
```

`file2.c`   --- incudes `file.h`

```
/*use `a`,`b` and` c` for some operation*/
```

`file3.c`   --- incudes `file.h`

```
/*use `a`,`b` and `c` for some operation*/
```

`file4.c`    --- incudes `file.h`

```
/* does not use `a`, `b` or `c`*/
```

Variables are declared as `extern` because same variables have to be used in multiple file.
Now the compilation is successfull for all files, but I get a linker error saying multiple definitions of `a`, `b` and `c` in `file2.c` and `file4.c` and also `file3.c` and `file4.c`:

```
Error-
unresolved extern a in file4.c
unresolved extern b in file4.c
unresolved extern c in file4.c
multiple definition  of a in file4.c and file2.c
multiple definition  of a in file4.c and file3.c
multiple definition  of b in file4.c and file2.c
multiple definition  of b in file4.c and file3.c
multiple definition  of c in file4.c and file2.c
multiple definition  of c in file4.c and file3.c
```

Since I am not using any variable in `file4.c` but only using function declaration defined in `file.h`,

### Question:

what could be the reason for the error?

Comment: Did you defined `a, b, c` in somewhere? Definition can be done like this: `int a, b, *c;`

Comment: Hmmm, it's my mistake. the problem is not undefined but multiple definition.

Comment: What is the **exact, verbatim error** you're getting. Edit your answer and add that!

Comment: variables are only declared in file.h which is included in every source file

Comment: Where are the variables defined?

Comment: Variable must NOT be defined in any header file.   Instead, in the header file use `extern` statements and in one (and only one) source file, declare the actual variables in the global address space (I.E. not within any function and not prefixed with `static`

Comment: the header file should also have 'include guards' I.E.  #ifndef FILE_H  #define FILE_H ..... #endif

Answer (score 3):

You can declare `extern [type] [variable-name];` as many times as you wish, in as many different **.h** files as you like, even multiple times within the same **.h** file.  (It would be pointless, but nothing prevents you from doing it.)

However, in order for even a single `extern [type] [variable-name];` to work without a linker error, you must also have one plain `[type] [variable-name];` (without `extern`) somewhere.

- If you do not have a plain `[type] [variable-name];` in some file, you get an "unresolved extern" linker error.
- If you have more than one `[type] [variable-name];` in different files, you get a "multiple definition" linker error.

So, what is most probably happening is that you are missing a plain `int a;` while you have multiple `int b;` and `int c;` somewhere.  These erroneous repetitions of `int b` and `int c` could be in different **.c** files, or they could even be in a single **.h** file, because each time the **.h** file is included by a **.c** file, it counts.

<strike>Thus, the best approach is to declare `int a;` in the file.h header file, and in every other file you would like to use the variable `a`, declare it as `extern int a;`.</strike>

Generally, the best approach is to declare `extern [type] [variable-name];` in a **.h** file included by all the **.c** files that need it, and `[type] [variable-name];` in *only one* of the **.c** files.

Comment: thnaks for the answer. i m relatively new to c. i have not declared a,b and c without extern anywhere else. where should i have variable declaration without extern as i have two files accessing the same variable. also, variables are not declared anywhere else with or without extern

Comment: place the actual declarations for the variables in one source file (and only one source file)

Comment: i dont declare variables in any c file ad am directly using them in source files ie assign it some values, would in such a case, the changed variable value be accessible in other files

Comment: If you don't declare variables in any c file, you get linker errors.  So, you have to fix that first.  And yes, once you do declare each one of your variables in exactly one of your c files, then their values will be visible from other files, by virtue of the `extern` declarations.